# Adding color to the NSView show a message: Layout still needs update after calling

Tags: xcode, swift, background, nsview

Do somebody know why xcode shows this message when adding this code to my program?

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    viewMenu.wantsLayer = true
    viewMenu.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blueColor().CGColor
}
```

> 2016-04-15 11:09:49.440 MyProgram[1828:34583] Layout still needs update after calling -[NSView layout].  NSView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout in the middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in Cocoa Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.

And how can I get ride of that?

The view is displayed correctly but shows the message above.